# device simulator not working in AEM 6

Tags: aem

The device simulator is not working in my AEM 6 (Mongo DB persistence manager) installation. It's throwing an error that's stopping my page from loading. I'm trying to open the demo geometrixx media site which has the required deice groups set. The stack trace of the exception is

```
*ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1410351155706] GET /content/geometrixx-media/en.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script head.jsp
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 103 in the jsp file: /libs/wcm/mobile/components/simulator/simulator.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
100:     });
101: </script><%
102:         } else {
103:             log.warn("mobile page [{}]: no device groups, cannot initialize emulators.", currentPage.getPath());
104:         }
105:     }
106: %>

at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:167)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:87)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.geometrixx_002dmedia.components.page.page_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f0(page_jsp.java:197)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.geometrixx_002dmedia.components.page.page_jsp._jspService(page_jsp.java:166)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:265)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:87)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:465)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:145)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:252)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:431)
at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:265)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:87)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:465)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:121)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.mercer.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:40)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:298)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hey, I am not able to reproduce the same but indeed - device simulator is very buggy for AEM6. We experience a lot of UX issues while simulator is attached for TouchUI interface i.e. you are not able to switch the device, or the page refresh redirects you to the home page. I believe this feature needs some love from the Adobe nowadays.

Comment: I have Java 8 running on my machine, could be the cause

Comment: Might be, I'm using java 7. Make sure you are using SP1 which is compatible with java8

Comment: Definitely Java 8 problem, Ran it with Java 7 and there were no errors

Comment: Hi @SharathMadappa Please post your solution so that everyone can see how you fixed it :) Thanks! (Your fix worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem today while trying to create a new AEM instance. Providing the fix as reference. As said in the comments the issue is due to java 8. As a solution run the aem jar with java 7 using command line.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -Xmx1024M -jar cq5-author-p4502.jar
pause
```

Run the above command from the folder where cq5 jar is present

**C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java** needs to be modified to the path of a java 7 JVM.

-jar **cq5-author-p4502.jar** should be the name of the jar

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved

This is an error from using Java 1.8 with AEM. AEM, at least 5.6.1 (the 6 I don't really know), can't be used with Java 8. You should install JDK 7 and use it in your PATH environment variable.